# FileUpload using selenium RC and java

Tags: selenium, java

I am using Selenium RC and Java and I need to automate the file upload feature.I tried a lot, Clicking on Browse button is not executing and rather getting stuck. I tried in FireFox  but to no avail.

Below is my code:I used different commands to load file ...like "type" & "AttachFile".pls can any one help me how to upload a file from "File Upload window".

```
RemoteControlConfiguration rcc =new RemoteControlConfiguration();
        rcc.setPort(3333);
        SeleniumServer ss = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
        ss.start();



DefaultSelenium  browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost" , 3333 , "*firefox" ,"http://");
        browser.start();
        browser.open("http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask");
        browser.windowMaximize();
        browser.setSpeed("20000");
        browser.click("id=nav-askquestion");
        browser.click("id=wmd-image-button");

//Used type command
             browser.type("id=upload-file-input", "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Home\\Desktop\\dropdown.jpg");

//Used AttachFile command
  browser.attachFile("id=upload-file-input","C:\\Documents and Settings\\Home\\Desktop\\dropdown.jpg");

//Used Runtime command
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Home\\Desktop\\dropdown.jpg");![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Can u Just post what kind of error message you are getting ..

Answer (score 2):

If the form is normal html form, you can skip opening the file upload dialog (which you don't need to test as hopefully you haven't implemented it yourself), and just enter the filename to the form field.

```
WebElement uploadInputField = browser.findElement(By.Id("upload-file-input"));
uploadInputField.sendKeys("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Home\\Desktop\\dropdown.jpg");
```

Comment: that's exactly correct.  i use it all over the place in my tests.  make sure you use the \\ instead of just a single \

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html), the second parameter to the `browser.attachFile` method is a URL, not a file path.  In your case, the URL will be something like `file:///C|/Documents and Settings/Home/Desktop/dropdown.jpg`.